# Cannot use 'bgcolor' in local scope [Pinescript] [tradingview]

Tags: view, pine-script, trading

Cannot use 'bgcolor' in local scope

my code :

```
//@version=4
//strategy("try 2", overlay=true) 
study("Astrolog 2", "Astrolog 2", overlay=true)
yearStart = 2015
yearEnd = 2021

for counter = yearStart to yearEnd [1]

   i_startTime = input(defval = timestamp("23 Aug 2020 00:00 +0000"), title = "Start Time", type = input.time)
   i_endTime = input(defval = timestamp("22 Sep 2020 23:59 +0000"), title = "End Time", type = input.time)
   i_length = input(defval = 20, title = "Length", type = input.integer)
    
   inDateRange = time >= i_startTime and time <= i_endTime
   bgcolor(inDateRange ? color.green : na, 50)

   break
```

I want every 23 Aug - 22 sept have background color

Answer (score 4):

```
yearStart = input(2015)
monthStart = input(8)
dayStart = input(23)

yearEnd = input(2021)
monthEnd = input(9)
dayEnd = input(22)

inDayMonthRange = time >= timestamp(year, monthStart, dayStart, 0, 0) and time <= timestamp(year, monthEnd, dayEnd, 0, 0)
inYearRange = year >= yearStart and year <= yearEnd

inRange = inDayMonthRange and inYearRange

bgcolor(inRange ? color.green : na, 50)
```

You don't need to use a loop, pine's execution model executes the script progressively through each historical bar.

`year` returns each bar's year portion of the timestamp. So as the script progresses through each historical bar, you can test separately if we are in the day/month range, and then also test if it is in your range of years.